# BATS assert_failure in nested function

Tags: bash, testing, exception, bats-core

### Context

While writing a test that expects an exception/error to be thrown, I am experiencing some difficulties detecting the error.

The code installs various software packages and tests each installation command separately. There is one function that does some preprocessing before each function and then calls the installation function, this managing function is called: `run_main_functions`, and it passes along arguments if they are entered. For completenes, the code of `run_main_functions` consists of:

```
#!/bin/bash
run_main_functions() {
    local SCRIPT_NAME=$1
    local EXTRA_ARGUMENT=$2
    SCRIPT_PATH=src/"$SCRIPT_NAME".sh
    local LOG_PATH=$LOG_LOCATION"$SCRIPT_NAME".txt
    
    chmod +x $SCRIPT_PATH
    
    # Remove old log files if exist
    if [ -f "$LOG_PATH" ] ; then
        rm "$LOG_PATH"
    fi
    
    # run the function that performs a single installation command
    if [ "$EXTRA_ARGUMENT" == "" ]; then
        source ./$SCRIPT_PATH $LOG_PATH
    else
        source ./$SCRIPT_PATH $LOG_PATH $EXTRA_ARGUMENT
    fi
}
```

This `run_main_functions` then calls a function `count_nr_of_lines` which I expect to throw an error if it is fed an invalid filepath. It consists of:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Count the total nr of lines in an incoming file and export it.
count_nr_of_lines() {
    source src/hardcoded_variables.txt
    
    local LOG_PATH=$1
    local INPUT_PATH=$2
    
    # read content from file
    text_content=$(<$INPUT_PATH)
    
    # count the number of lines in that app
    total_nr_of_lines=$(echo "$text_content" | wc -l)
    
    # 4. Write the result of the content check to a log file.
    echo $total_nr_of_lines > "${TOTAL_NR_OF_LINES_IN_TARGET_FILEPATH}"
}
count_nr_of_lines "$@"
```

And the test that checks whether the `count_nr_of_lines` throws an error if the `INPUT_PATH` is of a non-existant filepath is:

```
#!./test/libs/bats/bin/bats

load 'libs/bats-support/load'
load 'libs/bats-assert/load'
load 'libs/bats-file/load'

source test/helper.sh
source src/hardcoded_variables.txt
source src/helper.sh

mkdir -p src/logs

# Method that executes all tested main code before running tests.
setup() {
    
    # print test filename to screen.
    if [ "${BATS_TEST_NUMBER}" = 1 ];then
        echo "# Testfile: $(basename ${BATS_TEST_FILENAME})-" >&3
    fi
    
    # Declare filenames of files that perform commands
    declare -a script_names=("custom_install_4_energizedprotection")
    
    # Specify an additional array with arguments
    declare -a additional_arguments=("test/testfiles/nonexistant_filename.txt")

    # Loop through files that perform commands
    for i in "${!script_names[@]}"; do
        run_main_functions "${script_names[i]}" "${additional_arguments[i]}"    
    done
}

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@test "Tests whether an exception is thrown when computing the total nr of lines, if the file is not found." {
    ACTUAL_RESULT=$(<$TOTAL_NR_OF_LINES_IN_TARGET_FILEPATH)
    EXPECTED_OUTPUT="1"

    assert_failure
    #assert_equal "$ACTUAL_RESULT" "$EXPECTED_OUTPUT"
}
```

Where the filepath to the non-existant file is fed as:`"test/testfiles/nonexistant_filename.txt"`. The test fails with error:

```
✗ Tests whether an exception is thrown when computing the total nr of lines, if the file is not found.
   (from function `apt_update' in file ./src/custom_install_4_energizedprotection.sh, line 10,
    from function `source' in file ./src/custom_install_4_energizedprotection.sh, line 18,
    from function `run_main_functions' in file src/helper.sh, line 19,
    from function `setup' in test file test/test_custom_install_4_1_energizedprotection.bats, line 28)
     `run_main_functions "${script_names[i]}" "${additional_arguments[i]}"' failed
   ./src/custom_install_4_energizedprotection.sh: line 10: test/testfiles/nonexistant_filename.txt: No such file or directory
```

So in some sense, an error is thrown, which is expected, but I would expect the bats test to catch that error/exception, and yield a `passed test`.

### Question

How could I make the `bats` test pass succesfully by catching/registering the error that is thrown if the file does not exist?

### Attempts

I also tried to include an invalid path detection inside the `count_nr_of_lines` function with:

```
if [ ! -f "$INPUT_PATH" ] ; then
    exit 1
fi
```

to throw an explicit error, however, that removes the verbosity/error messages from the test failure and only results in a failing test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you're running the test code in the setup. How about this

```sh
setup() {
    # print test filename to screen.
    if [ "${BATS_TEST_NUMBER}" = 1 ];then
        echo "# Testfile: $(basename ${BATS_TEST_FILENAME})-" >&3
    fi
}

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@test "Tests whether an exception is thrown when computing the total nr of lines, if the file is not found." {
    #ACTUAL_RESULT=$(<$TOTAL_NR_OF_LINES_IN_TARGET_FILEPATH)
    #EXPECTED_OUTPUT="1"

    # this will report an error if it has a non-zero return status
    run_main_functions "custom_install_4_energizedprotection" "test/testfiles/nonexistant_filename.txt"

    #assert_equal "$ACTUAL_RESULT" "$EXPECTED_OUTPUT"
}
```

---

I missed the point that you are explicitly expecting failure.  You could

```sh
    ! run_main_functions ...
```

which will error if run_main_functions returns OK, or use [the `run` command](https://bats-core.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writing-tests.html#run-test-other-commands)

```sh
    run run_main_functions
    expect_failure
```

which I *think* will work, but I have a vague recollection about having to export sourced functions (I can't find any reference about that [in the docs](https://bats-core.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) though)

---

And after re-reading the docs, instead of `setup` use [`setup_file`](https://bats-core.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writing-tests.html#setup-and-teardown-pre-and-post-test-hooks):

```sh
setup_file() {
    echo "# Testfile: $(basename ${BATS_TEST_FILENAME})-" >&3
}
```

Comment: I think I did not explain the structure clearly, or lack understanding on what constitutes "test code". However, the `run_main_functions` is not test code, it is part of the installation module, that happens to be used by the test. You showed me that for this particular function that is being tested, the `run_main_functions` function can be omitted, to test less code at once. Your suggested solution results in output: `1 test, 1 failure`. Which seems expected as there is no `assert_failure` or something like that. I would expect a passing test if a failure occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by glenn jackman indeed led to a working solution. Based on my experimentation, the main issue was that the `assert_failure` should directly follow the line/command that is supposed to be failing. So when I put that line in the `setup()` or `setup_file()` that was not the case. Therefore, I moved the `run run_main_functions ..` command into the actual test and prepended `run` .

Furthermore, to verify that there was not an error with running the command itself, that was caught, I verified that the test `assert_failure` fails when that same command is executed in the test file while feeding the tested function a filepath towards a file that *does* exist.

In the function that is being tested, I could throw an error with `exit 1`, and that error is caught succesfully by the test.

Here is the function code:

```
#!/bin/bash


# Count the total nr of lines in an incoming file and export it.
count_nr_of_lines() {
    
    # Receive a filepath for which the amount of lines that it contains, is exported to a log file.
    local INPUT_PATH=$2
    
    # Throw an error with exit status 1 if the file does not exist.
    if [ ! -f "$INPUT_PATH" ] ; then
        exit 1
    fi
    
    # Read content from the input file.
    text_content=$(<"$INPUT_PATH")
    
    # Count the number of lines in that file.
    total_nr_of_lines=$(echo "$text_content" | wc -l)
    
    # Write the result of the content check to a log file.
    echo "$total_nr_of_lines" > "${TOTAL_NR_OF_LINES_IN_TARGET_FILEPATH}"
}


# Ensures this script executes the function above.
count_nr_of_lines "$@"
```

And here is the test code that I ended up using:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Load bats testing packages
load 'libs/bats-support/load'
load 'libs/bats-assert/load'
load 'libs/bats-file/load'

# Load hardcoded variables and helper functions.
source src/hardcoded_variables.txt
source src/helper.sh
source test/helper.sh

# Create the path to the log file folder.
mkdir -p src/logs

# Method that executes all tested main code before running tests.
setup_file() {
    
    # print test filename to screen.
    if [ "${BATS_TEST_NUMBER}" = 1 ];then
        echo "# Testfile: $(basename "${BATS_TEST_FILENAME}")-" >&3
    fi
}


#-----------------------------------Test execution of custom_install_4_energizedprotection.sh-----------------------------------------------
@test "Tests whether an exception is thrown when computing the total nr of lines, if the file is not found ERRROR." {
    # The test passes based if the assert failure directly follows this command (which throws an error because the file is not found).
    run run_main_functions "custom_install_4_energizedprotection" "test/testfiles/nonexistant_filename.txt"
    
    # The test fails if the assert failure directly follows this (working) command. 
    #run run_main_functions "custom_install_4_energizedprotection" "test/testfiles/hostfile_with_social_pack.txt"
    
    # Expect the command to fail when it is passed a path to a file that does not exist.
    assert_failure
}
```